# Contact points in collision

Tags: collision-detection, physics, physics-engine

I am making a GJK-EPA based collision detection routine. In this picture, the algorithm picks up on two contact points (the endpoints of the green penetration vector). I'm certain that the penetration vector (normal and depth) is correct, but the contact points seem to off by a translation - shouldn't they lie within the intersecting part?
[image: Collision]

Comment: After a shift by the penetration vector to separate the objects, those are the only two points in contact. Did you have a different definition of "contact point" in mind?

Comment: I was mostly worried about the direction of the angular velocity update to the regular pentagon in this case - but if it's all right, then I'm satisfied.

Comment: It's correct as far as the model you're using is concerned. That model makes approximations that will result in different collision response than a perfect continuous simulation. But perfection is usually more costly than it's worth. ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response! You can briefly make an answer if you deem it necessary

Comment: I'm still not sure what the original problem was. Can you explain how you've resolved the issue in an answer of your own?